# transpilation of .sass file into css is not working giving error for compass import in windows

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

The transpilation of the .sass file is not happening correctly. the css file created are having following error statement.
"Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass." in the generated css file

I have a angular app which has some .sass files it has been created with the help of yo angular command. 
 gruntfile.js :

```
compass: {
   options: {
   sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
   cssDir: '<%= yeoman.temp %>/styles',
   generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.temp %>/images/generated',
   imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
   javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
   fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
   importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
   httpImagesPath: '/images',
   httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
   httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
   relativeAssets: true,
   assetCacheBuster: true
},
  dist: {
   options: {
    generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
  }
},
server: {
options: {
  debugInfo: true
}
 }
},
```

I have ruby installed and the following gems are there.

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

- bigdecimal (1.2.4)
- bundle (0.0.1)
- bundler (1.10.0.pre)
- chunky_png (1.3.4)
- compass (1.0.3)
- compass-core (1.0.3)
- compass-import-once (1.0.5)
- ffi (1.9.8 x86-mingw32)
- haml (4.0.6)
- io-console (0.4.3)
- json (1.8.1)
- minitest (4.7.5)
- multi_json (1.11.0)
- psych (2.0.5)
- rake (10.1.0)
- rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
- rb-inotify (0.9.5)
- rdoc (4.1.0)
- sass (3.4.13)
- test-unit (2.1.6.0)
- tilt (2.0.1)

Comment: If you use the compass command directly, does it still give the same error?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your SASS file?

Comment: I think that was some compass version problem. rolling back to the older version solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

1. rolling back to the following version by first uninstalling the compass 1.0.3  and sass 3.4.13. Then installing the following version solved the issue.

   - gem install sass -v 3.2.9
   - gem install compass -v 0.12.7